# Query Expansion lucene

Tags: lucene, wordnet

I am new to lucene and I am trying to do query expansion.

I have referred to these two posts ([first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22585587/wordnetsynonymparser-in-lucene/36803316#36803316) , [second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11047466/does-any-one-know-how-to-expand-queries-using-wordnet-with-lucene-3-6)) and I've managed to reuse the code in a way that suits version 6.0.0, as the one in the previous is deprecated.

The issue is, either I'm not getting a results or I didn't access the results (expanded queries) appropriately.

Here is my code:

```java
import com.sun.corba.se.impl.util.Version;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardAnalyzer;
import java.net.URLDecoder;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.text.ParseException;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.Analyzer;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.TokenStream;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.Tokenizer;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.core.LowerCaseFilter;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.ClassicTokenizer;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardFilter;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.synonym.SynonymFilter;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.synonym.SynonymMap;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.synonym.WordnetSynonymParser;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.util.CharArraySet;
import org.apache.lucene.util.*;


public class Graph extends Analyzer 
{ 

  protected static TokenStreamComponents createComponents(String fieldName, Reader reader) throws ParseException{
      System.out.println("1");
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Tokenizer source = new ClassicTokenizer();

    source.setReader(reader);
    TokenStream filter = new StandardFilter( source);

    filter = new LowerCaseFilter(filter);
    SynonymMap mySynonymMap = null;

    try {

        mySynonymMap = buildSynonym();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    filter = new SynonymFilter(filter, mySynonymMap, false);     

    return new TokenStreamComponents(source, filter);

}

private static SynonymMap buildSynonym() throws IOException, ParseException
{    System.out.print("build");
    File file = new File("wn\\wn_s.pl");

    InputStream stream = new FileInputStream(file);

    Reader rulesReader = new InputStreamReader(stream); 
    SynonymMap.Builder parser = null;
    parser = new WordnetSynonymParser(true, true, new StandardAnalyzer(CharArraySet.EMPTY_SET));
    System.out.print(parser.toString());
   ((WordnetSynonymParser) parser).parse(rulesReader);  
    SynonymMap synonymMap = parser.build();
    return synonymMap;
}

public static void main (String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, IOException, ParseException
{
Reader reader = new FileReader("C:\\input.txt"); // here I have the queries that I want to expand 
TokenStreamComponents TSC = createComponents( "" , new StringReader("some text goes here")); 
**System.out.print(TSC); //How to get the result from TSC????**
}

    @Override
    protected TokenStreamComponents createComponents(String string) 
    {
      throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }
 }
```

Please suggest ways to help me access the expanded queries!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, are you just trying to figure out how to iterate through the terms from the `TokenStreamComponents` in your main method?

Something like this:

```java
TokenStreamComponents TSC = createComponents( "" , new StringReader("some text goes here")); 
TokenStream stream = TSC.getTokenStream();
CharTermAttribute termattr = stream.addAttribute(CharTermAttribute.class);
stream.reset();
while (stream.incrementToken()) {
    System.out.println(termattr.toString());
}
```

Comment: Thanks femtoRgon  This is exactly what I wanted !